# Have I ruined my brew before I even begin?

Tags: troubleshooting

I've a question. Have I ruined my brew?
I sterilised everything as normal. Got my 2 litres of boiling water and added the contents of my coopers Australian pale ale to it mixed it up with the spoon. Filled the fermentation bucket up to the 22.5L level. Seen it was at 25°c and pitched the yeast. Then had a sudden realisation what I'd missed. Forgot to add the brewing sugar. So I quickly opened my coopers beer enhancer 2 and added it on top of the yeast. Gave it a stir to break the sugar up. And sealed it up. What I'm wondering is because I pitched the yeast before adding the brewing sugar will it affect it in anyway? Because I added the sugar after I'd filled the bucket the total volume went up to 23.5L too. Also because I did it in a stupid order I had to take my o.g reading with the yeast pitched so will this effect anything?
Please help I made a right mess of this one.
Thanks James.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely nothing wrong with what you did.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest consequence of what you did is to add an extra liter of water. Your finished beer will be slightly lighter. For example, if it was to be 4.5% Alcohol by Volume, it might be 4.1-4.2% ABV instead. You probably won't notice the difference.